# InternedString as alternative to regular String

Tags: c#, performance, strings, hashcode

I need to use large strings as a dictionary keys, and I want to optimize the repetitive `GetHashCode()` and `Equals()` calls in it.

The number of keys will be quite small (<1000), but each string length will be very big (it's generated SQL queries cache), and I expect a lot of hot lookups.

My idea is to make sure that each wrapped string is interned, so that we can rely on the string references of the same strings to be always the same:

```
public sealed class InternedString : IEquatable<InternedString>
{
    public InternedString(string s) => String = string.Intern(s);

    public string String { get; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj) => String.Equals(obj);

    public bool Equals(InternedString other) => String.Equals(other?.String);

    public override int GetHashCode() => RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode(String);

    public static bool operator ==(InternedString l, InternedString r) =>
        l?.String == r?.String;

    public static bool operator !=(InternedString l, InternedString r) => !(l == r);
}
```

Can you review this class, with special attention to safety?

**UPDATE**

You can check the final code and benchmarks here: https://github.com/astef/InternedString

Usage:

```
// O(n) operation happens only here, so we want to re-use this object
var iString = new InternedString("typically_a_very_long_string_key");

// now any call to `GetHashCode()` and `Equals(...)` will run in a constant time
mySet.Add(iString);
```

Comment: It sounded like you were only asking for an opinion, I edited your question so that it fits more our format.

Comment: Safety against what?

Comment: I mean safety in general. Against bugs, against unexpected behavior. In particular, I was not sure if RuntimeHelper.GetHashCode is doing what I need, and if interning is reliable technique for this purposes, and if I'm not missing any corner-cases. It's just a few lines, but very low-level for me, and very critical for a program.

Comment: Could you please show the code using InternedString?

Comment: @KirylZ Check the Usage section here github.com/astef/InternedString. For a more real-world example, imagine a sql insert query which is need to be generated at some point, then executed once with saving results to dictionary, and then the results must be queried by a sql command.

Comment: @astef I think it'd be better if you could add an example to your post.

Comment: ASIDE: In case you want to "intern" strings for a long time but have them garbage collected eventually when they are no longer needed (i.e. objects handling them are disposed - like in a long running db-session for batch processing and then doing something completely different) you could use a [local pool](https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2015/02/12/string-interning-effective-memory-management-with-dotmemory/) instead.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming each time you receive a new query you create an instance of InternedString to get/add another item from/into the dictionary, the performance benefit seems questionable:

1. **Impact of string.Intern**

a) It needs to calculate a hash of the original string to make a lookup in the pool of strings

b) From [official documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.intern?view=netframework-4.5.2) -

> The memory allocated for interned String objects is not likely to be
>   released until the common language runtime (CLR) terminates. The
>   reason is that the CLR's reference to the interned String object can
>   persist after your application, or even your application domain,
>   terminates.

2. **High rate of collisions seems to be the only beneficial scenario**

The equality comparison that Dictionary does for items in the bucket is the case when you implementation might win when the bucket grows huge.

But do you really have that many collisions?

**P.S.**

Comparing strings you're not using **String.ReferenceEquals** to compare references of the interned strings, but rather == operator which for (sting vs string) leads to values comparison.

Comment: 2 - No, Dictionary and other hash-based collections call both `GetHashCode` and `Equals` on each lookup, not only for comparing items in a bucket.

Comment: PS - good point. Even while in a "true" comparison case it will lead to a reference comparison, in a "false" scenario O(n) comparison will be performed. It can be optimized

Comment: PS- I think that overloading `==` is a bad idea at all. And `Equals` is definitely need to do a reference comparison

Comment: Agreed on the second one. Will remove it. Good catch! As for ==, the general recommendation is to avoid using the == and != operators when you test for equality

Comment: Although given it more thought, the second point is still valid if remove the part "more than one items". As the more items it the bucket, the more gain you get comparing by references